# frida got error when hook too many methods

Tags: javascript

I just use default argument to hook method in ClassModel,and there is no overload for these method,but I got an error of "argument types do not match any of:.overload". this is my javascript code.

```
/*
ClassModels={
    "ClassNames":["cls1","cls2"],
    "cls1":["method1","method2"],
    "cls2":["method3","method4"],
    .....
}
*/

for(var ClassName  in ClassModels["ClassNames"])
{
    for(var MethodName in ClassModels[ClassName])
    {
        try{
            var clazz =Java.use(ClassName)
            clazz[MethodName].implementation=function(){
            if(arguments)
                send(arguments)
            var ret = clazz[MethodName].call(this,arguments)
            return ret
            }
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e)
            continue
        }
    }  
}
```

however when I hook one single method, there is no error. maybe I got the error because there is too many methods hooked, can anyone help me figure out this problem.

Comment: Please paste your code in the question, not as an image

Comment: I have pasted my code

Comment: Using frida-trace (which bases on Frida) you can hook hundred of methods at the same time. How many methods do you try to hook. May be you should better use frida-trace instead of trying to reinvent the wheel